# Mermaid diagrams and flow charts as a service

Tags: web-services, charts, diagram, svg, png

I am looking for a web-service (not downloadable software) which accept string or URL to [Mermaid diagram](https://github.com/knsv/mermaid) and return PNG or SVG image.

Service should accept this Mermaid string:

```
sequenceDiagram
    participant Alice
    participant Bob
    Alice->>John: Hello John, how are you?
    loop Healthcheck
        John->>John: Fight against hypochondria
    end
    Note right of John: Rational thoughts <br/>prevail...
    John-->>Alice: Great!
    John->>Bob: How about you?
    Bob-->>John: Jolly good!
```

And return this nice image:

[image]

Any suggestions? Experiences?

Comment: The mermaid website seems to feature a live editor. I am not sure whether it limits diagrams in size beyond any inherent limits of the software (after all, the Live Editor is probably meant for demonstration purposes, not as a regular web-based service), and the diagram sources seem to be encoded in some way, but *if* that encoding is known (maybe the live editor is open source, too?), a simple tool that builds the URL to that editor could be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: Typo: Mermain rather than Mermaid

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I would like to run it inside AWS Lambda one day :)